# django 1.7rc3 and celery 3.13 - AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: python, django, celery

This does not work for me

> $> cat /etc/lsb-release
>   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
>   DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
>   DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
>   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
>
> django 1.7rc3
>   celery 3.1.13
>   python 2.7

I attempt to run

```
celery worker -A <project_name>
```

and I get

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

The runserver command works fine so I don't think it has to do with my settings?

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

I've double checked celery.py and confirm it has the correct values for the following lines:

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

Is there something else i should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the reason this was failing is because i had this in one of my tasks.py

```
CURRENT_DOMAIN = Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

I got side steped this for now with

```
CURRENT_DOMAIN = lambda: Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

currently waiting to see if anyone on github cares to offer a better recommendation.
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2227

will update if i get one. If not will probably just do a helper function that lazy returns the value i want.

**update**
at the suggestion of celery author, I've refactored my code so I don't make that call at the module level.
He's also addressed the issue by making sure django.setup() is called before importing task modules
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2227

Answer (score 5):

Django 1.7 now requires a different initialization for [standalone scripts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#standalone-scripts).  When running outside the `manage.py` context, you now need to include:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Try adding it before the `app = Celery('proj')` in your script.

Comment: hi, if you see this issue: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2126 you will note that celery devs explicitly say not to call this in your celery.py

Comment: @w--, Yes, but it seems to work for people and celery devs don't adequately explain why not to call this in celery.py, or what to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue however only with:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER='djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Do you have this enabled? If I run it with the default celery scheduler it loads fine.  But can't get it to load with the Django scheduler.

Comment: with the latest version of celery, i don't think you are supposed to use djcelery anymore. I run celerybeat as a daemon and the only config i have in my settings.py is for CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = { <schedule definitions>}. since i haven't defined it i assume i'm using the default.

Comment: yeah I just like having the ability to create and manage jobs in dj admin.  Time to learn another method I guess :)